# How do you disable all keyboard shortcuts in an access form?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, shortcut, disable

I found a solution for this problem in excel vba.
I would like to have a similar solution in access vba.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the excel vba code that I found.

```
Sub Disable_Keys()
        Dim StartKeyCombination As Variant
        Dim KeysArray As Variant
        Dim Key As Variant
        Dim I As Long
    
        On Error Resume Next
    
        'Shift key = "+"  (plus sign)
        'Ctrl key = "^"   (caret)
        'Alt key = "%"    (percent sign
        'We fill the array with this keys and the key combinations
        'Shift-Ctrl, Shift- Alt, Ctrl-Alt, Shift-Ctrl-Alt
    
        For Each StartKeyCombination In Array("+", "^", "%", "+^", "+%", "^%", "+^%")
    
            KeysArray = Array("{BS}", "{BREAK}", "{CAPSLOCK}", "{CLEAR}", "{DEL}", _
                        "{DOWN}", "{END}", "{ENTER}", "~", "{ESC}", "{HELP}", "{HOME}", _
                        "{INSERT}", "{LEFT}", "{NUMLOCK}", "{PGDN}", "{PGUP}", _
                        "{RETURN}", "{RIGHT}", "{SCROLLLOCK}", "{TAB}", "{UP}")
    
            'Disable the StartKeyCombination key(s) with every key in the KeysArray
            For Each Key In KeysArray
                Application.OnKey StartKeyCombination & Key, ""
            Next Key
    
            'Disable the StartKeyCombination key(s) with every other key
            For I = 0 To 255
                Application.OnKey StartKeyCombination & Chr$(I), ""
            Next I
    
            'Disable the F1 - F15 keys in combination with the Shift, Ctrl or Alt key
            For I = 1 To 15
                Application.OnKey StartKeyCombination & "{F" & I & "}", ""
            Next I
    
        Next StartKeyCombination
    
    
        'Disable the F1 - F15 keys
        For I = 1 To 15
            Application.OnKey "{F" & I & "}", ""
        Next I
    
        'Disable the PGDN and PGUP keys
        Application.OnKey "{PGDN}", ""
        Application.OnKey "{PGUP}", ""
    End Sub
    
    
    
    Sub Enable_Keys()
        Dim StartKeyCombination As Variant
        Dim KeysArray As Variant
        Dim Key As Variant
        Dim I As Long
    
        On Error Resume Next
    
        'Shift key = "+"  (plus sign)
        'Ctrl key = "^"   (caret)
        'Alt key = "%"    (percent sign
        'We fill the array with this keys and the key combinations
        'Shift-Ctrl, Shift- Alt, Ctrl-Alt, Shift-Ctrl-Alt
    
        For Each StartKeyCombination In Array("+", "^", "%", "+^", "+%", "^%", "+^%")
    
            KeysArray = Array("{BS}", "{BREAK}", "{CAPSLOCK}", "{CLEAR}", "{DEL}", _
                        "{DOWN}", "{END}", "{ENTER}", "~", "{ESC}", "{HELP}", "{HOME}", _
                        "{INSERT}", "{LEFT}", "{NUMLOCK}", "{PGDN}", "{PGUP}", _
                        "{RETURN}", "{RIGHT}", "{SCROLLLOCK}", "{TAB}", "{UP}")
    
            'Enable the StartKeyCombination key(s) with every key in the KeysArray
            For Each Key In KeysArray
                Application.OnKey StartKeyCombination & Key
            Next Key
    
            'Enable the StartKeyCombination key(s) with every other key
            For I = 0 To 255
                Application.OnKey StartKeyCombination & Chr$(I)
            Next I
    
            'Enable the F1 - F15 keys in combination with the Shift, Ctrl or Alt key
            For I = 1 To 15
                Application.OnKey StartKeyCombination & "{F" & I & "}"
            Next I
    
        Next StartKeyCombination
    
    
        'Enable the F1 - F15 keys
        For I = 1 To 15
            Application.OnKey "{F" & I & "}"
        Next I
    
        'Enable the PGDN and PGUP keys
        Application.OnKey "{PGDN}"
        Application.OnKey "{PGUP}"
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I found with the help of a colleague of me:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Me.KeyPreview = True                        'turn keypreview on in order to receive all keyboard events
End Sub

Private Sub Form_KeyDown(keycode As Integer, shift As Integer)
sb_disablekeys keycode, shift
End Sub

 

Public Sub sb_disablekeys(keycode As Integer, shift As Integer)
    'All keyboard events with CTRL don’t function anymore with the exception of CTRL+C and CTRL+V
    ‘All keyboard events with ALT don’t function anymorge
    ‘All function keys are disabled
 
    Select Case shift
        Case acCtrlMask     ‘CTRL pressed
            Select Case keycode
                Case 0 To 16, 18 To 66, 68 To 85, 87 To 255
                'All keycodes with the exception of 17 (CTRL), 67 (CTRL+C) and 86 (CTRL+V) are set to 0.
                    keycode = 0
            End Select
        Case acAltMask      'Alt pressed
                    keycode = 0
    End Select

    Select Case keycode
        Case vbKeyF1 To vbKeyF16                ‘Function key pressed
            keycode = 0
    End Select
End Sub
```